# Filter Woocommerce pickup locations

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce

Using the 'Local Pickup Plus' extension by Woothemes, I want to edit/filter the pickup locations.  More specifically, I want to remove the province from each location.

[image]

I believe this is the filter I want to use:

```
    /**
 * Returns the array of shipping methods chosen during checkout
 *
 * @since 1.7.2
 * @return array of chosen shipping method ids
 */
public static function get_chosen_shipping_methods() {

    $chosen_shipping_methods = isset( WC()->session ) && WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) ? WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) : array();

    /**
     * Filters the chosen shipping methods
     *
     * @since 1.13.0
     * @param array $chosen_shipping_methods array of chosen shipping method ids
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wc_shipping_local_pickup_plus_chosen_shipping_methods', $chosen_shipping_methods );
}
```

This is my filter so far:

```
add_filter( 'wc_shipping_local_pickup_plus_chosen_shipping_methods', 'boltmobile_filter_pickup_locations' );
function boltmobile_filter_pickup_locations( $chosen_shipping_methods ) {
}
```

Before I can write the filter, I am getting error:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-shipping-local-pickup-plus/classes/class-wc-shipping-local-pickup-plus.php on line 891
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter two needed to be an array

```
add_filter( 'wc_shipping_local_pickup_plus_chosen_shipping_methods', $chosen_shipping_methods, 'boltmobile_filter_pickup_locations' );
function boltmobile_filter_pickup_locations() {
}
```